# How to skip the screen for Name/Organization in Inno Script installer

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup allows you to see a screen in which you are prompted to input your name and Organization.
How I can make my installer skip this screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To skip the Name and Organization input in InnoSetup script do the following:

```
UserInfoPage=no
```

Source: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_userinfopage

Answer (score 0):

For that page to appear, your setup must have explicitly implemented the `CheckSerial` event function. If you remove that then the page will also disappear.